# Calculating the area of part of the surface area $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ which lies inside the surface $x^2+y^2=2x$

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

The area of the part of the surface $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ which lies inside the surface $x^2+y^2=2x$ is equal to $n(\pi-2)$ for an integer n. What is the value of n?

**What I know so far:**

I get that my answer is $4(\pi-2)$ hence n=4?

Comment: one is a sphere, the other is ..

Comment: @GCab I managed to get an answer. Would you be able to verify that it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

One is a sphere of radius $R=2$, and the other is a cylinder of radius $1=R/2$.
Keeping the ratio of the radii, the area intercepted on the sphere shall be proportional to $R^2$ at varying $R$ : thus $n=2^2$

Comment: the answer was 8.

Comment: 8 is for the two (upper and lower) parts: deeply sorry not to have emphasized that :(